# c++ How to optimize a function that gets called very often?

Tags: c++, if-statement, optimization, inline

I have a function, lets name it isLinked(), that checks whether my object is linked to an other object of the same type. The problem is, the function gets called VERY often in a short timeframe. I'm talking about a couple of million times during a certain stage of processing information. Do you have any ideas on how we can optimize this? Should we use a dedicated bool per object? Or will that just create possible inconsistencies?  I'm not so familiar with code optimization. Note that we have a lot of objects in parallel that all do the same things.

So basically it comes down to this:

```
class MyObject() {
  private:
     MyObject* myLinkedObject;

 public:
     Bool isLinked(){
                return (myLinkedObject != NULL); 
     }

};
```

Then in other functions that are looped, we very often have a check like this:

```
if(myFirstLinkedObject->isLinked){
   .....
}
```

Comment: if it's only one line with simple comparison it will probably be inlined anyway. no need to be afraid of ~3-4 assembly lines.. beside, linked list is an anti performance container compared to dynamic array. if performance is your worry, switching to faster container may be the solution

Comment: Did you use a profiler to determine this function is a bottleneck?

Answer (score 2):

The bottleneck is definitely in a completely different place of code. This function is too simple and cannot be optimized significantly (you can hint compiler to make it inline, but I don't believe it'd have any significant performance gain).

As far as I can see, the problem is that you call this function is too often. Is there any reason for that? You should better to look at ways of optimizing code which calls this function, not to isLinked() itself.